# How to Solve the Wordpress Cron Job Site Slow down Problem?

Tags: themes, wp-cron

The Cron job has more data's which creates entry everytime when a page is loaded. So i tried to get a solution by searching about it. I got some clarifications. But no solution for my problem.

Many said to disable the `wp-cron` and create custom Linux cpanel based cronjob. But I feel to go with Existing WordPress one.

So i Googled again to get a solution. Someone told that, when you hook your `wp_schedule_event` function on the time of plugin activation.But I am using here in my `theme`.Is there any code available to schedule my cron job should be hooked only once, when the theme is activated like that.

Here is a piece of code which I get it. Don't know how to hook it better.

```
event_scheduler() {

    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'kv_daily_post_expire_check');

}
add_action('hook to run only once on the time of theme activation ', 'event_scheduler');
```

Comment: How often do you want your job to be run? Only one time? Or one time a day?

Comment: the function should work daily once. that's y i used `daily` there in the function itself.

Comment: [`after_switch_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme)

Comment: I tried it.  But it creates entries. Need something which can run only once than it won't work again.